# How to check MPMusicPlayerController permission?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have a viewController in my objective c application to show song list of my iPhone. The first time when I open this viewController, show the permission to use the music, but when I accept the permission, the tableView of all songs not refresh. 
Like this:
[image]

How can I check when the user click on allow to refresh the view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request authorization to Media Library programmatically fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374951/request-authorization-to-media-library-programmatically-fails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus;

switch (authorizationStatus)
{
    case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
    {
        break;
    }
    case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
    {

        break;
    }

    case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
    case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusDenied:
    {
        break;
    }
}
```